# Dynamic radio buttons in ionic 4

Tags: angular, ionic4

I'm new to ionic4. I used *ngFor to generate multiple cards and each card has a radio group. How to get the value of the radio group from each card?
I'm having a set of questions and each question will be displayed on each card. Every card has a radio group with 5 radio buttons. I need to get the value of the radio group from each card.

```
      <ion-header>
          <ion-toolbar color="primary">
            <ion-title color="light">
              <h1>title</h1>
            </ion-title>
          </ion-toolbar>
        </ion-header>
        <ion-content>
            <ion-card *ngFor="let question of questionnaire">
            <ion-card-header>
            <ion-card-title>
                <h4>{{question.title}}</h4>
            </ion-card-title>
            </ion-card-header>
            <ion-card-content>
              <ion-text><h6>Rating:</h6></ion-text>
                <div margin-vertical text-center>
                  <ion-grid>
                    <ion-row>
                        <ion-radio-group>
                      <ion-col>
                          <ion-radio value="1" ></ion-radio>
                      </ion-col>
                      <ion-col>
                          <ion-radio value="2"></ion-radio>
                      </ion-col>
                      <ion-col>
                          <ion-radio value="3"></ion-radio>
                      </ion-col>
                      <ion-col>
                          <ion-radio value="4"></ion-radio>
                      </ion-col>
                      <ion-col>
                          <ion-radio value="5"></ion-radio>
                      </ion-col>
                    </ion-radio-group>
                    </ion-row>
                  </ion-grid>
                </div>   
            </ion-card-content>
          </ion-card>
          <div margin-vertical text-center>
              <ion-button (click) = 'OnClickResponse()'>SUBMIT </ion-button>
          </div>
        </ion-content>
```

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { forEach } from '@angular/router/src/utils/collection';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-questionnaire',
  templateUrl: './questionnaire.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./questionnaire.page.scss'],
})

export class QuestionnairePage implements OnInit {

  public rating: any;
  public questionnaire: any;
  public i: any;
  public QA: any;
  public fetched = new Array(5);
  public randomArray = new Array(5);
  public value: any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public http: Http) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    let iterate: number;
    let random: number;
    const a: number[] = [1, 4, 0, 3, 2];
    const b: number[] = [0, 3, 1, 4, 2];
    const c: number[] = [4, 1, 2, 3, 0];
    const d: number[] = [2, 0, 4, 1, 3];
    const e: number[] = [3, 1, 0, 2, 4];

    this.http
      .get(url)
      .subscribe(response => {
        this.QA = response.json();
        console.log(this.QA);
        iterate = 0;
        for (let i of this.QA.data) {
          this.fetched[iterate] = i.content;
          iterate++;
        }
        random =  Math.floor(Math.random() * 5 + 1 );
        switch(random) {
          case 1:
            this.OnLoop(a);
            break;
            case 2:
              this.OnLoop(b);
              break;
              case 3:
                this.OnLoop(c);
                break;
                case 4:
                  this.OnLoop(d);
                  break;
                  case 5:
                    this.OnLoop(e);
                    break;

        }
      });


  }
  OnLoop(index) {
    let iterate = 1;
    for (let i of index) {
      this.randomArray[iterate] = i;
      iterate++;
    }

    this.questionnaire = [
        { title: this.fetched[this.randomArray[1]] },
        { title: this.fetched[this.randomArray[2]] },
        { title: this.fetched[this.randomArray[3]] },
        { title: this.fetched[this.randomArray[4]] },
        { title: this.fetched[this.randomArray[5]] }
      ];
    }
  OnClickResponse() {

  }
  }
```

Comment: Show your code.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to understand is that you are not building a jQuery / html style form, you are building an Angular app.

This means thinking about the way it is structured differently.

The form is not your "single source of truth". You don't present a form, let the user do what they want, and then at some point in the future pull that data back out of the form and process it.

What you need to do is build a data structure in the background code that represents the form. Then you two way bind that data to your form. This is what Angular specialises in.

As your user is making changes to the form the updates are synchronised to the data structure you set up in the background, so you always have easy access to it.

That means your page should look something like this:

// Template TS

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

export interface question {
  title: string;
  answer: number;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-questionnaire',
  templateUrl: './questionnaire.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./questionnaire.page.scss'],
})
export class QuestionnairePage implements OnInit {

  questions: question[] = [];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    // setup sample questions
    for(let i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
      this.questions.push({ title: `Example Question ${i}`, answer: undefined });
    }
  }

  getQuestionResults() {
    // no need to "get" the results
    // they are already bound to the questions property
    console.log(this.questions);
  }
}
```

// Template HTML

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar color="primary">
    <ion-title color="light">
      <h1>title</h1>
    </ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content>
  <ion-card *ngFor="let question of questions">
    <ion-card-header>
      <ion-card-title>
        <h4>{{question.title}}</h4>
      </ion-card-title>
    </ion-card-header>
    <ion-card-content>
      <ion-text>
        <h6>Rating:</h6>
      </ion-text>
      <div margin-vertical text-center>
        <ion-grid>
          <ion-row>
            <ion-radio-group [(ngModel)]="question.answer">
              <ion-col>
                <ion-radio value="1"></ion-radio>
              </ion-col>
              <ion-col>
                <ion-radio value="2"></ion-radio>
              </ion-col>
              <ion-col>
                <ion-radio value="3"></ion-radio>
              </ion-col>
              <ion-col>
                <ion-radio value="4"></ion-radio>
              </ion-col>
              <ion-col>
                <ion-radio value="5"></ion-radio>
              </ion-col>
            </ion-radio-group>
          </ion-row>
        </ion-grid>
      </div>
    </ion-card-content>
  </ion-card>
  <div margin-vertical text-center>
    <ion-button (click)='getQuestionResults()'>SUBMIT</ion-button>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

And would produce an app like this:

[image]

With an output like this:

[image]

What is important to realise is that if you set some code on the data structure then the value also updates in the UI:

```
this.questions[2].answer = 5;
```

Would select the radio button with value 5 for question 2:

[image]

You can use this idea when you put your JSON loading back in which I removed for the demo.

As a side note, it seems like you have started coding Angular / Ionic without doing any courses on Angular / Ionic. You will have more success if you learn the basics first.